# Eigen Library iterative methods for dense matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to solve a smoothing spline problem in C++ using *Eigen* library.

I set up the linear problem to solve and now I just need to implement
the code for the solver. So my problem is the standard linear system:

Ax = b

where A is a **dense matrix**.

First of all I want to make clear I am totally new to the *Eigen* library. I really hope not to ask a stupid question.

My idea was to use an *iterative method* to solve that problem. Looking on Eigen documentation I found a possible algorithm **LeastSquareConjugateGradient** that seems to work both with sparse and dense matrix.

I tried to compile an example and it worked fine using *SparseMatrix* class for matrix A, but it failed trying with *MatrixXd* class. In particular there are some problems when I use the *.compute()* method:

```
LeastSquaresConjugateGradient<MatrixXd> lscg2;
lscg2.compute(A);
```

Compiler errors are pretty incomprehensible to me:

```
In file included from /u/sw/pkgs/toolchains/gcc-glibc/5/pkgs/eigen/3.3.3/include/eigen3/Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers:39:0,
                 from /u/sw/pkgs/toolchains/gcc-glibc/5/pkgs/eigen/3.3.3/include/eigen3/Eigen/Sparse:33,
                 from prova.cpp:3:
/u/sw/pkgs/toolchains/gcc-glibc/5/pkgs/eigen/3.3.3/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/IterativeLinearSolvers/BasicPreconditioners.h: In instantiation of 'Eigen::LeastSquareDiagonalPreconditioner<_Scalar>& Eigen::LeastSquareDiagonalPreconditioner<_Scalar>::factorize(const MatType&) [with MatType = Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::OuterStride<> >; _Scalar = double]':
/u/sw/pkgs/toolchains/gcc-glibc/5/pkgs/eigen/3.3.3/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/IterativeLinearSolvers/BasicPreconditioners.h:170:23:   required from 'Eigen::LeastSquareDiagonalPreconditioner<_Scalar>& Eigen::LeastSquareDiagonalPreconditioner<_Scalar>::compute(const MatType&) [with MatType = Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::OuterStride<> >; _Scalar = double]'
/u/sw/pkgs/toolchains/gcc-glibc/5/pkgs/eigen/3.3.3/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/IterativeLinearSolvers/IterativeSolverBase.h:241:5:   required from 'Derived& Eigen::IterativeSolverBase<Derived>::compute(const Eigen::EigenBase<OtherDerived>&) [with MatrixDerived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; Derived = Eigen::LeastSquaresConjugateGradient<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >]'
prova.cpp:26:18:   required from here
/u/sw/pkgs/toolchains/gcc-glibc/5/pkgs/eigen/3.3.3/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/IterativeLinearSolvers/BasicPreconditioners.h:157:57: error: 'const class Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::OuterStride<> >' has no member named 'innerVector'
         RealScalar sum = mat.innerVector(j).squaredNorm();
```

So my naive solution was to converte *MatrixXd* into *SparseMatrix* through *sparseView()*. But I really think that is not computationally efficient.

So finally my questions:

- How bad is to convert a dense matrix to a sparse matrix through
  *sparseView()* to use **LeastSquareConjugateGradient** on it?
- (Or better) How can I use **LeastSquareConjugateGradient** with a *MatrixXd* matrix type?
- Or is there any other iterative method which works fine with *MatrixXd* already implemented in *Eigen*?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not using a direct solver? For dense problems, this is usually much faster and more reliable. For instance, you can follow the QR or normal-equation [guide](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__LeastSquares.html) .

Comment: btw, if you take the head of the 3.3 branch, then dense matrices work with `LeastSquareConjugateGradient`. This has been fixed a few weeks ago.

Comment: @ggael I was thinking about use a direct solver if my system is not too large, otherwise go for an iterative method. Do you think that QR/normal-equation scale better than iterative method when n is large with dense matrix?
Thank you for your comment!

Comment: What do you mean by large? 100, 1000, 10k, 100k, ? BTW, if you are using splines, I guess your matrix is sparse and has even a band structure right?

Comment: In my case they are not standard splines, because of some constraints, but maybe you are right about their structure. I will do some tests and look better in the literature to check the possibility of sparsity. Thank you!